How can I check if a variable is declared in "this" or not?
I am developing a function to assign a value to a property of this in Lightning Web Components (LWC) by passing its variable name. Additionally, I need to raise an error if the property is not declared in this.
How can I check if a property is declared in this?
P.S.

I do not want to check if a property is undefined, so typeof this[varName] === "undefined" will not solve my problem.
hasOwnProperty also does not work in LWC.


How do you figure that "hasOwnProperty" does not work in LWC?

It's true that this.hasOwnProperty("varName") will return false when this refers to an instance of a LightningElement class, even if the class has a property varName. Same for Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(this, "varName") and Object.hasOwn(this, "varName"), and even Object.keys(this).includes("varName"). I couldn't find a documented reason for this, but anecdotal evidence bears this out, at least in the testing I just did.
That said, you should be careful with key in object -- it will return true even if the property exists in the object prototype, which includes properties common to most objects.
As an example, even if you never create a property on your LightningElement called "lang", the following will return true, because lang is in the object prototype:
console.log("lang" in this);

Try this if you want to see everything that's in the object prototype -- the list is long, and includes some property names that could easily overlap with names you might choose to use in your app, like "id", "role", "hidden", "title", etc.:
for (const key in this) console.log(key);

My best suggestion here is to create a container object for all the properties you want to add or remove dynamically from the component, instead of doing so directly on the LightningElement instance. For example, this code works:
this.foo = { bar: 1, baz: undefined };
console.log(Object.hasOwn(foo, "bar")); // true
console.log(Object.hasOwn(foo, "baz")); // true
console.log(Object.hasOwn(foo, "lang")); // false


ChatGPT helped me with this problem.
I should use in in this case.
Here is an example.
if(varName in this) {
  // varName declared in this
  // so do something
} 

